# where o where are mounts specified in Ubuntu if not in /etc/fstab or /lib/init/fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab

I just inherited some Ubuntu boxes.

Trying to dope out what's what.  Possible emphasis on the word 'dope'...

I cannot figure out why 'df -h' lists the filesystem sizes that it does.

I want to change the values - such as grow /run - and I'd like my change to survive a reboot.  And I cannot find where the kernel is picking up 5.9G for /run on 1 box and 3G on another box...

I could use a little help here.

Thanks

Comment: Hard for us to answer with such little information. Post the output of the commands you question.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to grow /run?  Is there a problem?  It's all temporary stuff in ram (tmpfs), not on disk.  The system allocates whatever it needs as it boots, and it depends on the system as to how big it is each time.

The other things you see that are not in the ram-based tempfs (/run) are mounted using `/etc/fstab`, and that is mostly under your control.

Comment: These are dedicated MySQL servers and I've trying to get rid of some annoying /var/lib/mysql/mysql.error messages that appear to be caused by not enough space in /run.  When I dynamically grow /run using **mount -o remount,size=10G /run** the errors go away. Now I want to make that change permanent.  I assume that I can just put the line I need in /etc/fstab.  But since each server is running with different values for space on /run, I'm figuring those values are coming from SOME configuration file.  Or at least I'd like to understand the algorithm used at boot time to compute default values.

Comment: Maybe you just need more RAM; the /run ramdisk uses a percentage of RAM (50%, I believe).  There is also a file `/lib/init/fstab` that seems to specify the percentages to use, so you may be able to adjust it there.